# Best way to have a javascript load only on desktop version of site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, media-queries

I have a javascript (jQuery) that I am running on my WordPress site. I only want the script to load if the screen width is under 1024 pixels.

The reason for this is because it has to do with how the top navigation menu functions. I only want this script to load when the screen width is under 1024 pixels, because anything under that is going to have a completely different menu style / functionality.

Naturally I have plenty of media queries in my CSS file that change the design at min-width: 1024px.

I've found several ways to do this, I'm just trying to determine what the best way to do it would be.

Here is a copy of my current javascript file:

```
function accordion_menus(){

// if we are not on mobile (menu icon is hidden) show sub items and bail
console.log('debug: start');
if ( jQuery('#primary-navigation .menu-toggle').is(':hidden') ){

    console.log('debug: yes, it is hidden');
    // show sub menus
    $('#primary-navigation ul.nav-menu ul.sub-menu').show();
    return;
} else{
    // hide sub menus
    $('#primary-navigation ul.nav-menu ul.sub-menu').hide();
}

// top level nav click function
$('#primary-navigation ul.nav-menu > li > a').click(function(e){

// store parent li to variable
var parent_li = $(this).parent('li');

// if sub menu does not exist in parent li
if ( !$('ul.sub-menu', parent_li).first().length ) {
    return;
}

// if sub menu is already active, bail
if ( parent_li.hasClass('sub-menu-active') ){
        parent_li.find('ul').slideUp(100, function(parent_li){
});
            parent_li.removeClass('sub-menu-active');     

    return false;
}

// stop link click
e.preventDefault();

// store current sub menu in variable
var current_submenu = $('ul.sub-menu', parent_li).first();

// slide up non-current sub menus
$('#primary-navigation').find('ul.sub-menu').not(current_submenu).slideUp(function(parent_li){

    // remove sub-menu-active class from all first level items except current parent li
    $('#primary-navigation').find('li').not(parent_li).removeClass('sub-menu-active');

});

// slide down current sub menu
current_submenu.slideDown(100, function(){
    // add sub-menu-active to current parent li
    parent_li.addClass('sub-menu-active');
});

});

// second level nav click function
jQuery('#primary-navigation ul.nav-menu ul.sub-menu > li > a').click(function(e){

// store parent li to variable
var parent_li = jQuery(this).parent('li');

// if sub menu does not exist in parent li
if ( !jQuery('ul.sub-menu', parent_li).first().length ) {
    return;
}

// if sub menu is already active, bail
if ( parent_li.hasClass('sub-menu-active') ){
                parent_li.find('ul').slideUp(100, function(){

    // remove sub-menu-active class from all first level items except current parent li
});    
    parent_li.removeClass('sub-menu-active');     
    return false;
}

// stop link click
e.preventDefault();

// store current sub menu in variable
var current_submenu = jQuery('ul.sub-menu', parent_li).first();

// slide up non-current sub menus
jQuery('#primary-navigation ul.nav-menu ul.sub-menu > li > ul.sub-menu').not(current_submenu).slideUp(function(){

    // remove sub-menu-active class from all second level items except current parent li
    jQuery('#primary-navigation ul.nav-menu ul.sub-menu > li').not(parent_li).removeClass('sub-menu-active');

});

// slide down current sub menu
current_submenu.slideDown(100, function(){
    // add sub-menu-active to current parent li
    parent_li.addClass('sub-menu-active');
});

});

}

// load menu accordion on doc ready
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
accordion_menus();
});

// load menu accordion on window resize
jQuery(window).resize(function(){
accordion_menus();
});
```

Comment: what if i load your page on an ipad landscape (1024w) and then rotate it to portrait  (768w)?

Comment: It is easier to have a single script that checks the width and then decides itself whether to do its work or not.  The script can then subscribe to window size changes and can even adapt to a changing width.

Comment: Well, for the website I have it set to still retain a mobile style navigation (with the little menu button at the top that opens up a menu when you click it) up until 768 pixels. Anything 1024 pixels and beyond it switches to a fully open desktop style navigation.

So, that script in my mind should only load on widths that are under 1024 pixels in which it would need that script for the mobile style navigation to function properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    function resizeForm(){
        var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        if(width > 1024){

        } else {

        }    
    }
    window.onresize = resizeForm;
    resizeForm();
});
```

I've used this alot. Will rerun JS on each window resize. If you don't want that, just remove `window.onresize = resizeForm;`. Should work in all browsers hence the `width.innerWidth` check.

Comment: Per @jfriend00  I would make sure to write your CSS and JS so resizing won't break anything. Some people don't browse the internet at full screen but resize after the fact.

Comment: I like this solution, thank you! I didn't think to mention it in my original post, but it is important that the script rerun on each window resize. This helps in the instance that someone tilts their iPad (or other device) from landscape to portrait view (or vice versa). I just implemented this code and it works great so far! Thanks again!